# JPA Spring - Filter with a String

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-data-jpa

I have got Persons and I just want to get the ones starting with a certain letter (the letter is from an input field). Is is possible to get this without a query?
And how can I make this possible?

```
@Service 
public class PersonService { 

   @Autowired 
   private PersonRepository personRepository;         
   public Stream<Person> all(Person mysearch){ 
       return personRepository 
              .findAll(Example.of(mysearch)) 
              .stream() 
              .map(Person::fromPerson); 
  } 
}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person { 

    public Integer index; 
    public String firstname; 
    public String lastname; 
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy") 
    public Date exdate; 
    public String insnr; 

    private Person(Integer index, String firstname, String lastname, Date exdate, String insnr){ 
        this.index=index; 
        this.firstname=firstname; 
        this.lastname=lastname; 
        this.exdate=exdate; 
        this.insnr=insnr; 
    } 

    public static Person fromPerson(Person person){ 
        return person == null ? null : new Person(person.getIndex(), person.getFirstname(), person.getLastname(), person.getExdate(), person.getInsnr()); 
    } 
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired 
   private PersonService personService; 
   @RequestMapping(value="/person/list/**") 
   public List<Person> loadPersonList(   
                   @RequestParam(value = "firstname" ,required=false) String insnr) throws ParseException {         
       mysearch.setFirstname(firstname); 
       return personService.all(mysearch).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this without a query? You will be fetching a lot of redundant data this way which is slower. That's bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean :

```
String start = "";
return personRepository.findAll().stream()
              .filter(person -> person.getName().startsWith(start)) //<<---Note this
              .map(Person::fromPerson);
```

---

Or if you have insensitive cases you can use :

```
String start = "";
return personRepository.findAll().stream()
              .filter(person -> 
                      person.getName().matches("(?i)^" + Pattern.quote(input) + ".*"))//(1)
              .map(Person::fromPerson);
```

---

<sub>(1) For insensitive case, for example if your record is "Hello" and the input is "he" it will be selected, beside matches use regex, so your regex should look like `"(?i)he.*"`</sub>

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't work. When I try your suggestion nothing gets selected.

Comment: @Doe_123 can you share your input and some records you want to select please? check my second option please!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to filter with first name or last name

```
public List<Person> findByFirstNameLike(String firstName); // filter with firstname

public List<Person> findByLastNameLike(String lastName); // filter with lastname
```

or

```
public List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastNameLike(String searchKey); // return list of Persons that firstname or lastname like the searchKey specified
```